# Error when installing Orangehrm: Can't find any matching row in the user table

Tags: xampp, orangehrm

I'm trying to install Orangehrm on my laptop. I have Windows 7 OS on my machine and have installed XAMPP successfully. When I try to install OrangeHRM, it gives me the error: `Can't find any matching row in the user table`. [image] Can anyone tell me what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem. Hope this answer helps if someone is facing similar problems

- Step1: Installing XAMPP

  - Download the xampp installer
  - Install xampp (unselect the checkbox for perl)
  - Start apache and mysql from the xampp control panel
  - Check installation by opening browser (preferably firefox)
  - Type `localhost` in the address bar.
  - It should display the welcome page of xampp
- Step 2: Installing OrangeHRM

  - Download orangehrm
  - Unzip the file into `<xampp file location>\htdocs`
- Step 3: Set up Mysql manually

  - Start the Apache server and Mysql from xampp control panel
  - Open command prompt
  - Navigate to mysql\bin folder of xampp folder
    `cd <xampp_folder_location>\mysql\bin`
  - Enter the mysql command prompt by typing: `mysql.exe -u root`
  - At the prompt, type:
    `create database [orangehrm_db_name];`
  - Next, you need to create the tables.  Run the script at dbscripts Source
    `<xampp_folder_location>\htdocs\orangehrm\dbscript\dbscript-1.sql`
  - Please make sure InnoDB is enabled.

    - Switch into mysql/bin.
    - Open my.ini.
    - Add a # before `skip-innodb`
    - restart XAMPP.
  - Open the browser. Type in `http://localhost/orangehrm`
  - The orangehrm website should open.

Answer (score 2):

I just run into the same error and in my case the solution was to set a password for the OrangeHRM Database user.
The hint came from this "fixed" [ticket](https://sourceforge.net/p/orangehrm/bugs/221/).

Answer (score 0):

setting password for the user worked for me

Answer (score -1):

Try this one :

1. clean up your failed database insatalation.
2. Create manually database for OrangeHRM, (from phpmyadmin or mysql command promt)
3. Click install again from the step instalation

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As you can see, one of the answers has a green checkmark. It means this answer was accepted. On top of that it is a very detailed answer. I don't really see how yours answers better the question.